# Docusign: Can carbon copy recipients receive a notification when Signer views the envelope

Tags: php, docusignapi

Here's the logic I'm trying to follow:

1. A document is sent to the client
2. The client views the document
3. The client signs the document

I want my carbon copy recipients to get an email when (1)The document is sent, (2) the document is viewed, (3) the client completes the document.

Currently, the carbon copy receives an email when (1) the document is sent, and (3) the client completes the document. They do NOT get an email when (2) the document is VIEWED.

The SIGNER however, gets an email during (1) and (3), but ALSO when the CARBON COPY views the document.

I don't need the signer to get an email when the carbon copy views the document, I just need them to get the first email and a confirmation email when the document is complete.

Here's my code using the DocuSign PHP client:

```
// ...
// ... Other logic 
// ...

// Signer
$signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer->setEmail($config->getRecipientEmail());
$signer->setName($config->getRecipientName());
$signer->setRoleName('Signer');
$signer->setRecipientId("1");
$signer->setRoutingOrder("2");

// CC
$carbonCopy1 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\CarbonCopy();
$carbonCopy1->setName($config->getCarbonCopy1Name());
$carbonCopy1->setEmail($config->getCarbonCopy1Email());
$carbonCopy1->setRoleName('Carbon Copy');
$carbonCopy1->setRecipientId("2");
$carbonCopy1->setRoutingOrder("1");

$signer->setTabs($tabs); // Previously set 

// Add a recipient to sign the document
$recipients = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners(array($signer));
$recipients->setCarbonCopies(array($carbonCopy1));

// ...
// ... Other logic 
// ...

$envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
```

Note: No errors are being thrown.
Note: Behavior is the same regardless of whether or not I set the role of each recipient.

Comment: "_The SIGNER however, gets an email during (1) and (3), but ALSO when the CARBON COPY views the document._" Do you mean the Sender gets the emails?

Comment: @CodingDawg No, the person who's supposed to fill out the form (i.e. the client) sees when someone from our company (i.e. the carbon copy) views the document

Comment: I am pretty sure the signer will not receive an email when the CC recipient views the envelope. Can you please share the envelopeId you created so that I can look up how you have setup your recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Carbon copy](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/) recipients receive their copy of the envelope when the envelope reaches the recipient's order in the process flow and when the envelope is completed.

Recipient viewed notifications will only be sent to the Sender.

Email Notifications are controlled in the Sender & recipient settings and can be managed [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications) . They cannot be controlled through the envelope definition.

---

As a **Sender** you can receive the following notifications

- A document that I have sent is complete
- A document that I have sent has been assigned to a different signer
- A signer has declined to sign a document that I have sent
- A signer has withdrawn their consent to do business with me online
- A document I have sent has been viewed by a recipient for the first time
- A document has failed to be delivered to a recipient
- A document I sent will be purged from the system

As a **Recipient** you can receive the following notifications

- I need to sign a document
- A document that I have signed is complete
- I am designated to receive a copy of the document
- I need to acknowledge receipt of a document
- I need to approve changes another recipient has made
- I need to provide contact information for other recipients
- Another recipient has declined to sign a document
- The sender has voided the document
- The sender has corrected the document
- A recipient reassigns a document to me
- A document I received will be purged from the system
- My fax has been received

Comment: While testing, the signer email and the email I use with my docusign developer account were the same, so I was being mistaken by believing that the signer was seeing when the carbon copy was reviewing the document, when in reality it was simply my developer account being informed (because they were the same email). Basically, huge mistake on my part that I only realized after reviewing your answer. So thank you.